# How to recognize iphone call events in my application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, events, call

I wish to detect the call state after my app resumes the active state from the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at core telephony [here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html)

Comment: Can you explain with example ?Please.

Comment: @user601367: some people might consider that to be too broad a question.  Try reading the linked docs on Core Telephony, then come back with specific questions about bits you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Core Telephony, but note that it is only available in recent versions of iOS.

Comment: Can you give me some examples on it ?Please.

Comment: Read the documentation, then let us know if you have any questions. We can't do all your work for you.